# Handling multiple checkbox with one OnClickListner in Android?

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a scrollview which contains a list of checkboxes, now I have to set a value of integers corresponding to each checkbox depending on its state. I can do this by applying onClickListner for every checkbox but I think I am not thinking it straight and it can be done with just one cliclListener like we do in case of buttons by implementing onClickListener. Help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use single `OnClickListner` and use `switch case` statement

```
public void onClick(View v){
  switch(v.getId()){
     case R.id.checkbox1:

      break;

      case R.id.cbox2:

       break;

      ............and so on

   }
}
```

and set this onClickListner for Your whole View.

Comment: I think once the case if matched it will by pass all other cases but I want to check all of them at once. Correct me if I misinterpreted.

Comment: you can use fall-through by removing break; statement where you dont want to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add an onTouchListener or onClickListener on scrollview. When touched you can take child element which is touched. Then you can handle things.